# Purpose of throttle with parameter Func<TSource, IObservable<TThrottle>> throttleDurationSelector

Tags: c#, system.reactive, throttling, rx.net

All the documentation I found about rx.net throttling does not cover the overload with a parameter `Func<TSource, IObservable<TThrottle>> throttleDurationSelector`. So all I have available are the XML-comments. This suggests, that `throttleDurationSelector` is called on every new element in the source sequence. The expected return value would be a `IObservable<TThrottle>`. (My understanding) This enables the possibility to change the throttle-delay on every new element. But, this understanding does not match the runtime experience I discover.

```
var s = new Subject<string>();
s.Throttle(_ => Observable.Return(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))) // for simplicity of this demo, always return the same delay
    .Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}.{DateTime.Now.Millisecond} event {_}"));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    s.OnNext("a");

Thread.Sleep(1000);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    s.OnNext("b");

Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

According to the previously mentioned understanding (which is obviously wrong), I'd have expected the following output.

```
10.02.2022 11:47:54.386 event a
10.02.2022 11:47:55.388 event b
```

Instead this output is generated. It seems that there is no throttling applied at all.

```
10.02.2022 11:46:49.431 event a
10.02.2022 11:46:49.432 event a
10.02.2022 11:46:49.432 event a
10.02.2022 11:46:49.432 event a
10.02.2022 11:46:49.432 event a
10.02.2022 11:46:50.448 event b
10.02.2022 11:46:50.448 event b
10.02.2022 11:46:50.448 event b
10.02.2022 11:46:50.448 event b
10.02.2022 11:46:50.449 event b
```

What is the purpose of this overload, if not dynamically changing the throttle-delay (which is what I need)?

Also, why the 'complicated' syntax of `Func<TSource, IObservable<TThrottle>> throttleDurationSelector` where a simpler parameter `Func<TSource, TThrottle> throttleDurationSelector` would be good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are talking about this overload of the `Throttle` operator:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Throttle<TSource, TThrottle>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IObservable<TThrottle>> throttleDurationSelector);
```

The intention of the `throttleDurationSelector` parameter is to give you maximum flexibility at how you define the throttle duration for each element. The value of the `TThrottle` is not important. What is important is when it emits an element (any element), or when it completes. This is how the duration is defined, by observing dynamically the `TThrottle` sequence, and waiting it to emit any kind of notification.

Going back to your code, you are returning an `Observable.Return` as the throttling sequence. This sequence emits a `TimeSpan` element immediately, causing the associated `string` element of the source `s` sequence to be also emitted immediately. The result is that no throttling occurs. It is equivalent to throttling with a `TimeSpan.Zero` argument, or with removing the `Throttle` operator altogether.

To fix your code, you must replace the `Observable.Return` with a sequence that emits an element with a delay, like an `Observable.Timer` sequence. So if you know the throttling duration immediately after receiving a `TSource` element, and let's say for simplicity that it is always 500 milliseconds, you can just replace this:

```
s.Throttle(_ => Observable.Return(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)))
```

...with this:

```
s.Throttle(_ => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)))
```

Comment: I would have loved to have seen a clear discussion as to why the OP's code didn't behave as expected. It can be deduced, but it is not clearly stated.

Comment: @Enigmativity do you approve the updated answer with the enhanced explanation?

Comment: That is an excellent discussion. Thank you for indulging me.